# Longest Uncommon Substring

Tags: code-golf, string

For the purposes of this challenge a *substring* \$B\$ of some string \$A\$ is string such that it can be obtained by removing some number of characters (possibly zero) from the front and back of \$A\$.  For example \$face\$ is a substring of \$defaced\$

\$
de\color{red}{face}d
\$

This is also called a *contiguous* substring.

A common substring of two strings \$A\$ and \$B\$ is a third string \$C\$ such that it is a substring of both \$A\$ and \$B\$.  For example \$pho\$ is a common substring of \$photochemistry\$ and \$upholstry\$.

\$
\color{red}{pho}tochemistry\\
u\color{red}{pho}lstry
\$

If we have two strings \$A\$ and \$B\$ an *uncommon* substring of \$A\$ with respect to \$B\$ is a third string \$C\$, which is a substring of \$A\$ and has no common substring of length 2 with \$B\$.

For example the longest uncommon substring of \$photochemistry\$ with respect to \$upholstry\$ is \$otochemis\$.  \$otochemis\$ is a substring of \$A\$ and the the only nonempty common substrings of \$otochemis\$ and \$upholstry\$ are size 1 (\$o\$, \$t\$, \$h\$, and \$s\$).  If we added any more onto \$otochemis\$ then we would be forced to permit a common subsring of size 2.

### Task

Given two strings \$A\$ and \$B\$ output the maximum size an uncommon substring of \$A\$ with respect to \$B\$ can be.  You may assume the strings will only ever contain alphabetic ASCII characters.  You can assume \$A\$ and \$B\$ will always be non-empty.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

### Test cases

```
photochemistry, upholstry -> 9
aaaaaaaaaaa, aa -> 1
aaaaabaaaaa, aba -> 5
babababababa, ba -> 2
barkfied, x -> 8
barkfield, k -> 9
bakrfied, xy -> 8
```

Comment: Not that it affects the challenge, but the correct spelling is *upholstery*.

Comment: @Dingus I fudged it a bit for the sake of the example, so that *stry* would be a common substring as well.

Comment: Suggest `barkfied, k -> 8` that 1c B is ignored

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 8 bytes

```
ü«å_γO>à
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8J5Dqw8vjT@32d/u8IL//wsy8kvykzNSczOLS4oquUqB/BwQCwA) or [Try all cases!](https://tio.run/##Tc3BagIxEAbge57iPwjbanaDgqAge9OrL7C0JJuRBHUjmxUVfJheeuqx1566977SNulWdAZmho9hRklvulI2yFE6TZnzUlnCYoHletW1X98f7fvrz@c6b9@6IIydjN0RapIatmLaMYBK4zCwFa7wpJHWSLx4ecpGzxyxIs2RDQeiGBesmIgk7Al3aET/6789vg9nK@oOxjWuNLS3vqkvHMcAuzjGe3Mm78EhZcRxj@qG6k@nTMl7cvQ6CVpvN5Y0xznCjP0C)

**Explanation:**

The longest uncommon substring is the longest sequence of adjacent length 2 substrings of \$A\$ that are not substrings of \$B\$.

```python
ü«        # length 2 subtrings of A
  å       # for each substring: is it a substring of B?
   _      # logical negation
    γ     # split into list of equal adjacent elements
     O    # sum each section
      >   # increment each sum
       à  # take the maximum
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I had `ŒéʒŒ2ùå_P}θg`, where the `Œ2ù` could be golfed to your `ü«`. +1 from me. The `_P` could alternatively also be `O_` or `à_`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 58 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,s=1:a>''and+max(f(a[1:],b,a[:2]in b or-~s),s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc7BCsMgDAbg@54ieGnd3KHbTehepPQQV0VZq6IO2ste3ekYmEAg359D/JG0s/ec1bjiJhYEZILFceD46Dq0y2XDvVc9TgOfS4ITv83GggAXrp9IWaRZuQBJxgTFe@K1S@6p5WZiCgdhQN6F1t9CWTnAVjUts7FoLP4usHUNmoeXMnKpthPKTwA@GJvKs@f6DaX5Cw)

Comment: and here I am struggling with `1+max((len(list(g))for k,g in itertools.groupby(a[i:i+2]in b for i in range(len(a)))if not k),default=0)`

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>11 10</s>  9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 using [ovs's observation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235642/53748).

```
;Ɲẇ€ṣ1ẈṀ‘
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/62NyHu9ofNa15uHOx4cNdHQ93NjxqmPH//3/1goz8kvzkjNTczOKSokr1/@qlQJEcMBsA)**

---

##### 10 byter

```
Ẇ;ƝẇƇ¥ÐḟṪL
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrjbrY3Mf7mo/1n5o6eEJD3fMf7hzlc/////VCzLyS/KTM1JzM4tLiirV/6uXAkVywGwA)**

#### How?

```
Ẇ;ƝẇƇ¥ÐḟṪL - Link: A, B
Ẇ          - sublists of A (from shortest to longest)
      Ðḟ   - filter discard those for which:
     ¥     -   last two links as a dyad, f(substringOfA, B):
 ;Ɲ        -     length 2 sublists of substringOfA
    Ƈ      -     keep those (pairs) for which:
   ẇ       -       is this pair a sublist of B?
        Ṫ  - tail -> longest uncommon substring
         L - length
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 63 bytes

Expects `(B)(A)`.

```javascript
b=>g=([c,...a])=>a+a&&Math.max(g(a)-1,g=!b.match(c+a[0])*-~g)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc7BDoIwDAbgu0@BHMgmMMTERA/jDXwCwqEbsKHACEyDF199QjBZhL@XtumX9A4vGHhfdTpsVV6YkhpGE0FRygNCCGSYJuCD591AS9LAiAQCHMaBoHs2zZpLxH1Ijxk@hB@B/dhw1Q6qLkitBCqR@@ykqgfdv12M3KnXisuiqZYNdqLIue5WBGC@BZv50GYi8YYwa9jWTOS8JotgYGtNTmsyLqJ/lFWR/z/1IxfzBQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
b =>             // main function taking the 2nd string b
g = ([           // g = recursive function taking the 1st string as:
  c,             //   c = next character
  ...a           //   a[] = array of remaining characters
]) =>            //
  a + a &&       // stop if a[] is empty (and return a zero'ish value)
  Math.max(      // otherwise, take the maximum of:
    g(a) - 1,    //   - the result of a recursive call, minus 1
    g =          //   - the updated value of g, which is:
      !b.match(  //     - 0 if b contains c + a[0]
        c + a[0] //     - g + 1 otherwise
      )          //   NB: all recursive calls have already been processed
      * -~g      //   when this part of the code is reached; so it's OK
                 //   to re-use g as a counter (initially zero'ish)
  )              // end of Math.max()
  + 1            // increment the result to make it 1-indexed
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <del>33</del> 32 bytes

```
(?=(..).*¶.*\1|.*$).
;¶
P`.+
\G.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X8PeVkNPT1NP69A2Pa0Ywxo9LRVNPS7rQ9u4AhL0tLli3PX@/09MSk5JTUvP4CooSk1LTAIA)

-1 thanks to Neil.

Takes the strings \$A\$ and \$B\$ separated by a line feed for the input.

First, a Replace stage looks for each character in \$A\$ that when combined with the next character forms a pair that can be found in \$B\$ (`(..).*¶.*\1` in the lookahead), as well as every character of \$B\$ (`.*$` in the lookahead). Each of those characters is replaced by a semicolon followed by a line feed. This breaks \$A\$ into pieces that are uncommon with respect to \$B\$ and \$B\$ into individual characters, except with `;` in place of the last character of each piece. Each piece is on a separate line.

Next, a Pad stage matches each whole line, and pads all of them to the longest length present.

Finally, a Count stage matches each character in the first line (because `\G` makes the matches have to be consecutive, and `.` does not match line feeds), and produces the number of such characters.

Comment: Last line can be `\G.` to save a byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Just can't seem to do better than 13.

```
ä@VèZÃôÎmÊÍÌÄ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=5EBW6FrD9M5tys3MxA&input=InBob3RvY2hlbWlzdHJ5IgoidXBob2xzdHJ5Ig)

```
ã2 ô!øV ñÊÌÊÄ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=4zIg9CH4ViDxyszKxA&input=InBob3RvY2hlbWlzdHJ5IgoidXBob2xzdHJ5Ig)

```
ä@VèZÃôÎmÊÍÌÄ     :Implicit input of strings U & V
ä                 :Consecutive pairs of U
 @                :Map each Z
  VèZ             :  Count the occurrences of Z in V
     Ã            :End map
      ô           :Split on elements with
       Î          :  A truthy sign (i.e., 1)
        m         :Map
         Ê        :  Length
          Í       :Sort
           Ì      :Last element
            Ä     :Add 1
```

```
ã2 ô!øV ñÊÌÊÄ     :Implicit input of strings U & V
ã2                :Substrings of U of length 3
   ô              :Split on elements
    !øV           :  Contained in V
        ñ         :Sort by
         Ê        :  Length
          Ì       :Last element
           Ê      :Length
            Ä     :Add 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 80 bytes

```python
f=lambda b,a,*r:{*zip(a,a[1:])}&{*zip(b,b[1:])}and f(b,*r,a[1:],a[:-1])or len(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYrBCsMgEETv@QrJoWiwpaG3QL@k5LAmSqSJymqgaem3WxsPUjrLDjv7xm1hsuYSo7rOsIgRiODAG@xezVM7Chxubdez9yFnwUXOYEaiUmwwN5J3x7ZnFsksDQUW9eIsBuI3X6U9eRlQDit6bc2sFx1oe97FqsqhNoEqWq9usrMPuNWc1OkOdpjkovcPY6UH8C1A0S8VBYt/nKmAMj/4kSnelZZjIvED)

Yes! Longest continuous substring again.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 18 bytes

```
⟨s{s₂ᶠ¬{∋~s}}⟩ᶠlᵐ⌉
```

Takes a list containing strings \$A\$ and \$B\$ as input; produces the longest length as output. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8FcXVxY@amh5uW3BoTfWjju664traR/NXAvk5D7dOeNTT@f9/tFJBRn5JfnJGam5mcUlRpZKOglIpUCgHzIn9HwEA)

#### Explanation

Implements the spec pretty directly:

```
⟨            ⟩      "Sandwich" construction:
 s                  The output is a substring (C) of the first string in the input (A)
  {         }       which satisfies this predicate with respect to the second string (B):
   s₂ᶠ               The list of all length-two substrings of C
      ¬{   }         does not satisfy this predicate:
        ∋             There exists an item in the list
         ~s            which is a substring of B
             ᶠ     Find all substrings that satisfy the sandwich predicate
              lᵐ   Length of each
                ⌉  Maximum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>156</s> <s>107</s> <s>105</s> 99 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 85 bytes** by replacing two `function` appearances with `\`s.

```r
function(x,y,r=rle(!sapply((1:nchar(x))[-1],function(k)grepl(substr(x,k-1,k),y))))max(0,r$l[r$v])+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RctRC4IwEAfw9z6FmQ8bTWhBUIF9EfFhsy1lU8epsX36tWXpHRzc/f4HXhZezn09tUOPLHEECtAC7UdmjHYI0XtfNwyQxbjMaUXWrMIvEEajcebjFJyonBKFicOhOmbRiUCmS8jeFT5SL1FqmmEa6kZ0bXhwKUnSOZz0d8GHJH8kt12Isa1iJswF6Yp8Q/7XS1TOto686nlRULIVzyj2B1f/AQ)

Port of [@ovs's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235642/55372).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ẆẆḊƇẇ€SʋÐḟẈṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrjYQ2tF1rP3hrvZHTWuCT3UfnvBwx/yHuzoe7mz4f3i50v//SgUZ@SX5yRmpuZnFJUWVSjoKSokIAOcmwblJiQio9F@pFKg/B6ETTCZBFSoBAA)

### How it works

```
ẆẆḊƇẇ€SʋÐḟẈṀ - Main link. Takes A on the left, B on the right
Ẇ            - All contiguous substrings of A
       ʋÐḟ   - Keep substrings S for which the dyadic link f(S, B) is 0:
 Ẇ           -   Substrings of S
  ḊƇ         -   Remove singleton lists
     €       -   Over each substring:
    ẇ        -     Is B a contiguous substring?
      S      -   Sum
          ẈṀ - Get the maximum length
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 19 bytes

```
U#MX J(_.BNIbMPa)^0
```

Takes the two strings as command-line arguments. [Try it here!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) Or, here's a 20-byte version in Pip Classic: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fW1vZN0LBSyNez8nPM8k3IFEzzuD///8FGfkl@ckZqbmZxSVFlf9LgfwcEAsA)

#### Explanation

Based on [ovs's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235642/16766):

```
U#MX J(_.BNIbMPa)^0
             MPa     Map this function to each pair of characters in a:
       _.B            Concatenate them together
          NIb         Return 1 if that string is not in b, 0 if it is
     J(         )    Join the resulting list of 1s and 0s into a single string
                 ^0  Split it on 0s
  MX                 Take the maximum (i.e. the longest run of 1s)
 #                   Get its length
U                    Increment
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 14 bytes

```
K'2lv∑⁰vca¬;tL
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=K%272lv%E2%88%91%E2%81%B0vca%C2%AC%3BtL&inputs=hello%0Agolodbye&header=&footer=)

A bit messy.

```
K              # Substrings
 '         ;   # Filtered by...
         a¬    # None of...
  2lv∑         # Substrings of length 2
       vc      # Are contained in...
      ⁰        # The second input
            t  # Get the last (and longest) element
             L # Get its length
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 37 bytes

```
${#Last[{_&Has\`@&1\y==[]}\x]}:Slices
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxBC4JAEIXv/oqFxJOXroIQdOkQEdRtXWrUNRe3lJ0JXMTfvq1Qmb13Gb7vMUAERS1dxZLUhcNqD0h8uEQ7wOy6idaZTVMuxqwXY3LSqpDoDlKWyMOuK24iOBr1oLNE2gJK5FEVMx4wHz@oW2r977tCMjZm4dMTPd0ifk9gjvcAS5F/RT6bHOZ6tTCmqZQsPe3/oZ6o/aGN@UytCIRwLw)

### Explanation

```
${#Last[{_&Has\`@&1\y==[]}\x]}:Slices
${                           }           a function taking inputs x and y
                              :Slices    ...where x = Slices[x] and y = Slices[y]
        {                }\x             all members _ of x where
                   \y                     |the elements of y which
               `@&1                       | |have a char at index 1 (i.e., length >= 2)
         _&Has\                           | |and are contained in _
                     ==[]                 |is the empty list
   Last[                    ]            obtain the last such member
  #                                      and return its length
```

### Golfing Process

**41 bytes:** `${#({None[_&Has,{#_>1}\y]}\x)[-1]}:Slices`

**41 bytes:** `${#Last[{None[_&Has,{#_>1}\y]}\x]}:Slices`

**40 bytes:** `${#Last[{None[_&Has,{_@1}\y]}\x]}:Slices`

**39 bytes:** `` ${#Last[{None[_&Has,`@&1\y]}\x]}:Slices ``

**38 bytes:** `` ${#Last[{#(_&Has\`@&1\y)<1}\x]}:Slices ``

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 38 bytes

```
{#*((1&/^(2'y)?2')')#,/(''|1+!#x)[;x]}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxVju1qwyAYRv+/V+HMmLq5hQQKbV7YbqL/Qkd1a2gwJcV1oHTbtc8o+agBCec84Gmqa/bIefGQv/OSefFWMsFEJnPO2E/xdJc5UaPb/QJsq+t97f9s1ZAX4nDfG+T7RrUdOvRoRdhsa07Px/7SfxwPp/brYj1F+h1IF/8FbnZxo+YTBuESWCyMnowe1CopreYvuKjKUVnTtIdPipK6gNc3uIvczM9rZWyaU+fTHHK4DZdk6ibPr2QDi2ZJlBpgAYvcAHWkK1iWSpJoCWOkJG4Aa5jyJDHpjTEsTHza/AOK8Xsv)

Takes `A` as `x` and `B` as `y`.

- `,/(''|1+!#x)[;x]` generate all substrings of `A`, with the longest first
- `(...)#` filter, keeping only those items where `(...)` has `1`s

  - `((...)')` apply the code in `(...)` to each item in the list being filtered
  - `2'` take 2-length substrings of the current item
  - `(2'y)?` retrieve their indices in the 2-length substrings of `B` (returning `0N` (null) if it is not present)
  - `1&/^` keep items where none of their 2-length substrings are present in `B`
- `#*` return the length of the first (longest) uncommon substring

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>144</s> 124 bytes

Naive approach, much room for golfing.

```python
lambda a,b,l=len,r=range:max(l(c)for c in(a[x:y]for y in r(l(a)+1)for x in r(y))if all(c[n:n+2]not in b for n in r(l(c)-1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBBa4QwEIXP668YvGjY2YJbCq3Uhb0UCj0U9uh6mESt0hglpqC/3k4U2eSS@ea9yUuG2TW9eV7q7L5o6mRJQChRZ7oyaDNL5qdKO5piHStR9xYUtCamfErnwpczl2C5S@KYrIJpI7MQbQ2k2Zeb1BzPhemdb0nwKrP7lDglQojFVaMbIYMwDIemd71qqq4dnZ0R/hhof4TTBd4CeiwEIg@TDcodypW@BJIeG2GjZ6b2t26rEjkrg1e@8mkcdOvi6G4iEQQ@oM/jM6650uBAEhXH8@Uu9maWH/jDuENy57hShSXT1jh@ItYxixgO1oM8@rh@fkUYfV9vt6jIVZaVBa6z2ft@4QmlWP4B)

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>119 bytes</s> 116 bytes

```cpp
int f(char*a,char*b){char*c=b,s=0,l=0;for(;a[1];*a++?l=l>++s?l:s:0)for(b=c;b[1];)*a-*b++|a[1]-*b?:s=*a=0;return-~l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZLdboIwGIbPuYrGnciPCaBIQq1eiPHga4FJqGAKJC7O3Tr7ENDqltA26c/zvE3TVpzPi08h2jYrapLOxRGUBc694@b13gvGnYq5jmQuTUs1p7D3DtQC295JJre2Xe1kVEWu2UHOBOUdNy1YWNy2vzsbR7uoYhbgFiqpG1UsfiS9tR9ZIWQTJ2STlVWtEjhtDaM7yQmyYm6Sq0FIdwYC3v5AGJmdj2VdimNyylD/mtGR84E3KMhXBH6P4Fm03ANqgaUW4O@BEXI9seoXOTyrFnlQLRGMaypPsyTW7IFcNHn9IkvdHlCu2eFo5@pt64Fc@tvBVtVxFImyqclmg68PnoM3aXaTO0mKWNJ/NB81f1pborac1laoraa1ALVgWlujtp7WQtTCvxq2/n8Slxq39hc)

I used ovs' characterization of longest uncommon substring as the longest sequence of adjacent length 2 substrings of \$A\$ that are not substrings of \$B\$ (plus 1).

I only use `C++98`. The function takes two C-strings as input and modifies the first one. <s>I chose not to abuse the `?:` feature in `gcc`, but that would save at least 1 byte.</s> Following ceilingcat's comments, I guess it doesn't hurt to use non-standard code (using `?:`, UB with bitwise OR `|`). This saves 3 bytes.

#### Explanation

```cpp
int f(char* a, char* b) {               // Take two C-strings as input
  char* c = b;                          // Remember the start of b
  char s = 0;                           // Current sequence length
  char l = 0;                           // Longest sequence length

  for (; a[1]; ++a) {                   // Iterate until before last character
    for (b = c; b[1];) {                // Similar
      if (*a != *b++ or a[1] != *b) {   // Compare pairs of characters
      }
      else {
        s = 0;                          // Reset current sequence length
        *a = 0;                         // Flag to indicate sequence reset
      }
    }
    if (*a) {                           // Check if sequence is reset
      ++s;                              // Increment current sequence length
      l = l > s ? l : s;                // Update maximal sequence length
    }
  }
  return l + 1;                         // Increment to get substring length
}
```

Comment: @ceilingcat, using bitwise OR `|` raises a warning, unsequenced modification. Is there a guarantee in `gcc` for this? Thanks for the `-~l` tip, I saw that in another submission but didn't know what it did ^^

Comment: I think it depends on how strict you want to be. Many of us don't mind UB or unportability.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
Ｉ⊕Ｌ⌈⪪⭆Φθκ¬№η⁺§θκι0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcxBCsIwEEDRvacIXU0ggntXIggFWwo9wTSZJsE0qelUevsYBP/68bXDrBOGUobsI8MdN4Y26kwLRSYDT4qWHXR4@GVfYFyDZxi5YtvhCg8fmDK8lXhJJfpUD2mvH6fEEPYNbtxGQ8cfeFlTork08te1FJy0odm605ppxqmcP@EL) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Based on @ovs' approach.

```
       θ            Input A
      Φ             Filter out
        κ           First character
     ⭆              Map over characters and join
             §θκ    Previous character
            ⁺       Concatenated with
                ι   Current character
         ¬№         Is not found in
           η        Input B
    ⪪            0  Split on `0`s
   ⌈                Longest string of `1`s
  Ｌ                 Length
 ⊕                  Incremented
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```